# How to mock different responses for the same path?

Tags: node.js, nock

I'm using `nock` to mock http responses in my integration tests.
I want to return different responses for sequential requests.

For example, for the first 10 requests to `/api/movies` I want to return 200,
then I want to return 404, and then 200 again.

Something like this:

```
nock('http://app.com')
  .get('/api/movies')
  .times(10)
  .reply(200)
  .get('/api/movies')
  .times(1)
  .reply(404)
  .get('/api/movies') 
  .times(20)
  .reply(200)
```

But it seems it just execute the first definition.
How can I do it?